# how do I get mixed JSON and TSV data into a data frame?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a file that I am trying to read into Pandas, but the main problem is the file has a mixed format of JSON and tab separated values (TSV).  Here is an image of the file loaded into a dataframe: [image]

Comment: I'm trying to load/parse this data nice a clean into the data frame. Preferably with columns labeled as the keys in the dictionary which are "company", "catch_phrase "phone" etc...

Answer (score 0):

So if my understanding is correct, You want to load a tsv file as a pandas dataframe right?

Assuming you have a tsv file.

`df = pd.read_csv("path to the tsv file", sep="\t")`

This will load your tsv file as a DF.

Then what you can do is iterate over the column that has your json.

```
for col in df[["columnname"]]:
    obj = df[col]
    for item in obj.values:
        json_obj = json.loads(item)
```

Comment: so that gets me access to the dictionary in the header column.
What I'm having an issue with is getting access to the other dictionaries that are in the dataframe.  its really weird

Answer (score 0):

This is verbatim a homework question for the UMich Data Science degree, so I won't answer in detail. That said, my overall successful approach was to read in the file as a list, and then evaluate each item in the list with a for loop. Since each item came in as a string, if it looked like a JSON object, I used json.loads() on the item to convert it to Python dictionary format. If it did not look like a JSON object, I used .split() and then created a dictionary of key-value pairs with the given keys, and subsetting each element of the split as a value. Clunky, but it worked.